Getting 403 Forbidden in Spring Boot Controller Test with MockMVC
I'm encountering a 403 Forbidden error when running a Spring Boot test for my SetupController using MockMVC. Despite mocking the JWT validation to return true, the test still fails with a 403 status. Below are the relevant code snippets for my controller and test class.
SetupController.java:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/setup")
public class SetupController {

    @PostMapping("/createSummary")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER') or hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    public void createChallengeSummary(@RequestHeader String Authorization) {
        if (!jwtValidator.isValidJWT(Authorization)) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid JWT Token");
            return;
        }
        String userEmail = jwtValidator.getUserEmail(Authorization.substring(7));
        LOGGER.info("Creating ChallengeSummary for user with Email: {}", userEmail);
        reportsService.createChallengeSummary(userEmail);
    }
}

SetupControllerTest.java:

@WebMvcTest(SetupController.class)
public class SetupControllerTest {


    private final String AUTH_HEADER = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhbGV4QGZobXMuZGUiLCJhdXRoIjoiVVNFUiIsImlhdCI6MTcxNjkwMTAxMiwiZXhwIjo0ODcwNTAxMDEyfQ.YgqbpgTBpRSmPMAY1-t9UVXAvIVigEjKSHeM8axslIGVFUozeacYfb3VLPvGJ99RWf3C8q5UjMmhpBEAPlzVgyHUFhj_6NUHkYuTcFFGIvdAClQ00RIIbNhx0g23PrQFo7AZtF1m6BbLe6QQUU12gEH4XYq4hL0p4BV9iNRnSdSHK-vLGuP9jSLFwOQRzMkWEBMfvn6w4mQWlQuBG9Zi6hjg5b4meOHUvQJeVr_sAHq2e15ig292ndisAVbQ1VP6-91-qpmOQ4-O36o_DUUVCaSDV4Gup9lE4Deu0UPdaYTR0UuSmfZx0e3DnQufwKUokqNUwdgzfRnwLIvXekgwAA";
    private final String TEST_USER_EMAIL = "harry@fh-muenster.de";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername(TEST_USER_EMAIL)
                .password("***")
                .authorities("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();

        when(jwtValidator.isValidJWT(any(String.class))).thenReturn(true);
        when(jwtValidator.getUserEmail(any(String.class))).thenReturn(TEST_USER_EMAIL);
        when(jwtValidator.resolveToken(any(HttpServletRequest.class))).thenReturn(AUTH_HEADER.substring(7));
        when(jwtValidator.getAuthentication(any(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "",
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateChallengeSummary() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(post("/rest/setup/createSummary")
                .header("Authorization", AUTH_HEADER))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print());

        verify(reportsService).createChallengeSummary(TEST_USER_EMAIL);
    }
}

JWTValidator.java:

@Component
public class JwtValidator {

    public boolean isValidJWT(String jwt) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser()
                    .verifyWith(publicKey)
                    .build()
                    .parseSignedClaims(jwt);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Token rejected because " + e.getMessage());
            throw new InvalidException("JWT invalid");
        }
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String jwt) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(getUserEmail(jwt), "", getRoles(jwt));
    }

    public String getUserEmail(String jwt) {
        final Jws<Claims> token = Jwts.parser()
                .verifyWith(publicKey)
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(jwt);
        final Claims payload = token.getPayload();
        return payload.getSubject();
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the user roles from a JWT.
     *
     * @param jwt
     * @return
     */
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getRoles(String jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<>();
        final Jws<Claims> token = Jwts.parser()
                .verifyWith(publicKey)
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(jwt);
        final Claims payload = token.getPayload();
        final String authClaim = payload.get("auth", String.class);
        if (authClaim.equals("USER")) {
            result.add(Role.USER);
        } else if (authClaim.equals("ADMIN")) {
            result.add(Role.ADMIN);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public PublicKey getPublicKey() {
        return this.publicKey;
    }
}


Mocking JwtValidator to always return true for isValidJWT.
Ensuring the Authorization header is correctly passed in the request.
Mocking the user details with appropriate authorities.

Issue:
Despite these setups, the test still results in a 403 Forbidden error.
Questions:

Is there something wrong with my test setup or Spring Security configuration?
Are there additional configurations needed for Spring Security to allow the mock setup to work properly?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Handing out jwts to browsers is not recommended so why are you building a non recommended authentication. Why havnt you read the docs?
